# Styling map: Change JSON file programmatically

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a JSON file in `row/my_map_style.json` andI am styling map according to that json file.

```
MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this.context, R.raw.my_map_style);
map.setMapStyle(style);
```

It works fine. Now I want to change the JSON file programmatically,  basically, I will get JSON data from edit text when user enter then store it in same raw file and style map.

but I can't figure out how do I change already saved json file when user type json data in editext? is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a browser, you can't change local files in the client's file system.

What you can do is either save the data as JSON in "local storage" (browser has to support it), a cookie (user has to allow it) or send the data to the server, where it is either saved in a file or in a database.

Comment: user will enter exact copy of json they get from browser. i just need it to store existing json file and load the map